# Can a screw terminal jack handle high speed (> 100 Mbps) Ethernet?

Tags: lan, rj-45, cat6

The builder ran Cat-6 cable through the walls, and then installed these [screw-on RJ-45 Ethernet jacks](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Network-and-Coax-Wall-Plate-217F-8C-WH/203715579):

To my eye, because the twisted pairs are untwisted for an inch or two, it's highly unlikely these will support anything over 100 Mbps. Am I being overly persnickety?

Comment: "Color coded"? "2.4 GHz"?? Judging by the wire coloring, those aren't even supposed to be Ethernet jacks... (Multiple phone lines?)

Comment: Looks like phone to me. Colors match some European phone standards. I sincerely doubt that this will do 100 mb/s.

Answer (score 1):

These are certainly not Cat5e-compliant. Gigabit Ethernet (IEEE 802.3 1000BASE-T) is engineered to work over 100 meters of Cat5e. However, it *might* work over shorter distances of lower-quality cable such as these jacks. So it *might* work for you, and there's no way to know for sure other than to try it. I, personally, would strongly prefer to use equipment that is properly engineered to meet Cat5e requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As you state, there would would be *some* discontinuity in impedance, which causes signal loss and reflection. On the other hand, the Ethernet physical layer is somewhat fault tolerant.

Therefore, the *only* way to find out if the whole physical network can handle higher speeds is to test it, which you can easily do [over the internet (WAN)](https://testmy.net/city/peer_be) or more specifically, over your local area network (LAN) with [peer-to-peer speed test tools for Windows](https://download.cnet.com/LAN-Speed-Test/3000-2085_4-10908738.html) or [for Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7976/how-do-you-test-the-network-speed-between-two-boxes). Such a test would also check the cabling, which might have a severe crimp, as well as the connectors and wall plate.

Answer (score -1):

Not compliant and ive read many complaints. Would work for phome line and maybe 10/100 if your lucky but I would go with proper keystones and 110 punch downs all the way for proper ethernet use. Most builders use to them to save a bit of money assuming people will just use them for phones